# Anchor tag not working from other pages in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, laravel

I am using laravel 9.26.1 with react. I have a single page application with a couple of anchor tags. The anchor tags are working fine when you are already using the website, but they do not scroll to the desired section and just sit on top of the page when you use them from another website or paste the link in directly.

Example of how I use the anchor tag
`<li><a href="/#about-us">About us</a></li>`

I tried to take the links out of the React component and paste them into laravel blade, but it didn`t fix it.

I have also tried:

`<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/#about-us">About us</a></li>`

`<li><a href="{{ route('main').'#about-us' }}">About us</a></li>`

`<li><a href="{{ route('main') }}/#about-us">About us</a></li>`

All of them produce the same effect. I have been stuck on this bug for hours.

My tags are defined as `<div id="about-us" className="anchor"></div>`

Comment: Since react apps are rendered after the page loads essentially, the anchor would not exist when the browser looks for it. You could either add JS code to scroll manually or use SSR to solve this (I have not really found a good SSR solution for Laravel though)

Answer (score 0):

why using `(/)` before `(#)`
just use `(#)` without any `(/)`
eg:

```
<li><a href="#about-us">About us</a></li>
```

Comment: Because my website also has some sub-directories and the links wouldn't work in them. But this doesn't solve the problem, as it is occuring when you go from these mentioned sub-directories.